# MySQL join on null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Product:

```
id | sku
0    P323
1    K534
```

Translation:

```
product_id | lang | name
0            en     Some product
0            sl     Nek izdelek
1            en     Some other product
```

Now, I need to display the Slovenian (sl) translation, but if it does not exist, the English one should be displayed.

I am looking for a way to fetch the products where the result is as follows:

```
id | sku  | name
0    P323   Nek izdelek
1    K534   Some other product
```

Is this possible with MySQL, with a single query?

Note: the entry in the translation table maybe does not exist or exists but all the values (except the foreign keys) could be null.

EDIT by request:
I need to have an option, to let the privileged backend user to create as many text fields as the e-store needs them for a product display (e.g. short description, what's in the package, warranty info...). Therefore I would rather not hardcode column names into the SQL query, as this decreases portability.
I would need to select all translation fields without specifying the column names, as in "translation.*" .
If no practical solution is found, I'll resort to maintaining a record of custom columns which are added when the query is built (prior to executing it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both translations are missing name is display as NULL

```
SELECT p.id, sku, IFNULL(tr.name,en.name) as name
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN translation en ON p.id = en.product_id and en.lang = 'en'
LEFT JOIN translation tr ON p.id = tr.product_id and tr.lang = 'sl'
```

see also docs for [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

OR with the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) for better perfromance

```
SELECT p.id, sku, COALESCE(tr.name,en.name) as name
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN translation en ON p.id = en.product_id and en.lang = 'en'
LEFT JOIN translation tr ON p.id = tr.product_id and tr.lang = 'sl'
```

Comment: [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) would be a better choice than `isnull`.

Comment: you are right for performance but `ifnull` is more _readable_ and more intuitive to understand

Comment: Nice, but one thing I forgot to mention is that I'll let the backend user dynamically add as many text fields to the product translation table. Is there a way to do the above without specifying the columns? Else I'll have to keep metadata records about the table structure.

Comment: @OmerSabic - when you show an example, please include how you determine the order of importance for a language.

Comment: I've added additional explanation in the original post, basically I want to do "coalesce" but with the entire joint table (where values are null).  
@Lieven the order of redundancy is specified in the backend config. Only the first in line is to be performed in the SQL query (as it is the most promising/appropriate one) - to avoid more joins (the product query already has several, without the translations).

Comment: @xdazz: It isn't really about performance or getting the same functionality, COALESCE will work with more databases than IFNULL will, choosing the more standard/portable approach over a database-specific one is usually a good idea. There's a lot more to the database world than MySQL.

Comment: @omer Sabic .. if I understand you right you want a solution not tied to **name** you want more columns like **description**, **size**, **weight** which are automatic generated by some users ... That general query cant be made .. therefor you had to change your table to **product_id**, **lang**, **typ** (name,weight,description...), **word** (for type name -> Nek izdelek) ... if I got you wrong please add a substantial example ..

Comment: Too bad, but isn't it weird such a functionality does not exist? Seems like a legit scenario and not some crazy exotic idea. Anyway, thanks!